# How to add a chat messenger feature in an Android application?

Tags: android, chat

I am developing an Android Application. I wanted to include chat feature in it. I tried to search Scringo but it has shut down since February 2015. Kindly suggest some alternative solution for the problem. 1:1 chat constraint is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Developing your own chat platform takes time and efforts.
There are many companies who provides chat as a service :

- Applozic
- List item
- Sendbird
- Layer
- Quickblox

read more in this [article](https://www.applozic.com/blog/applozic-vs-sendbird-vs-layer-vs-quickblox-discover-your-best-chat-sdk/).

Answer (score -1):

I have wondered same many times. It is not an easy task, and it would require :

- IP address
- Socket number for connection
- possibly phone number of peer
- a server which monitors incoming messages and generates outgoing ones
- database- local and at server push notifications possibility

You can start from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/).

Maybe if a direct connection between ip-ports can be made between peers, a server won't be needed but then again the app won't be very dynamic since a server would make sure message transfer even when the device is in idle state (like whatsapp)

I am sure if broken down to one task at time, it won't be a big challenge.

Best of luck!

Comment: the link you specified is about developing a group chat app. But my app is about helping people for preparing for recruitment process. In that app I need a chat messenger feature for interaction between the members. So I just wanted some way in which i could include it in my existing application